# How to parse a local XML file in browser?

Tags: xml, local

We have a website that has the option to search. We want to put this website on a CD and we want to preserve the search functionality. Because we want it to function offline also we can't use a database sow e thought we use an XML file as "storage".

Now the problem is that we can't read the local xml file using javascript because some browsers consider this a security problem.

How to read and use a local XML file for our offline website? What technology can we use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always embed a signed java applet. This will give you full filesystem access. The java applet can read and parse the XML file and send the data to a JavaScript function on your page.